# What does "a fear of he was not certain what" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> A sort of premonitory tremor, a fear of he was not certain what, had passed through Winston as soon as he caught his first glimpse of the cage.
> (which is quoted from the sixth or maybe the ninth paragraph in the fifth chapter in the third part of the novel.)

When I was reading Orwell's 1984, I found the phrase "a fear of he was not certain what" difficult to understand. What is the meaning of it? I would appreciate it if you would answer my question.

I would also like to know how the phrase is constructed grammatically, if you could tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: It's a "quirky" construction, effectively "forced" on Orwell because English doesn't have a succinct way of expressing *fear of **something**, the precise nature of which he was uncertain about*. Even most native speakers would probably have to pause and perhaps re-read the words to properly parse them. You might think of it as an unavoidably klunky way of saying ***a fear of X (where 'he' is not certain exactly what 'X' actually is)***

Comment: compare *He could see **something** (he wasn't certain exactly **what**) moving in the back of the cage.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have

> a fear of the dark
> a fear of heights
> a fear of failure
> a fear of God
> a fear of something happening

and generally

> a fear of <noun phrase>

where the noun phrase describes a thing that frightens you.

> he was not certain what

is your noun phrase, which can be put differently

> something he was not certain about

He didn't understand what he was afraid of.